# Simple facebook Oauth2 graph use in ruby

Tags: ruby, oauth, koala

When I want to use the Facebook graph API to look up information like friends or wall postings, I get an error saying I have to authenticate with Oauth2.  I'm not trying to create an app or anything for other users on the web.
I just want to be able to authenticate and poke around the graph API in my linux box from a script.

I tried using Koala and so far I've got:

```
@oauth = Koala::Facebook::Oauth.new(app_id, secret, callback_url)
```

I'm not exactly sure what to put for callback_url so I used [this](https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html) one.

`@oauth.get_app_access_token` seems to get me something that looks like an oauth access token, but I'm unable to use it with the graph api ... any help out there?

Answer (score 1):

Do you understand the basics of [fbgraph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)?

In general you can only query public information, for example:

https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola

To query private information you need an access token. Read the [authentication guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) which provides details of Facebook's OAuth 2.0 implementation, how to request permissions from a user and obtain an access token.

In the [Koala documentation](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) you can read:

> You can use the Graph and REST APIs without an OAuth access token, but the real magic happens when you provide Facebook an OAuth token to prove you're authenticated. Koala provides an OAuth class to make that process easy: @oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(app_id, app_secret, callback_url)